# Use each record of table A as field of table B in access

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm trying to figure out maybe a simple problem. I need to create a kind of attendance tracker and use as field of one table, records from another one.

Example:

**TABLE A WHERE I HAVE ALL NAMES OF USERS**

| NAME | INFO |
| --- | --- |
| Name 1 | detail 1 |
| Name 2 | detail 2 |

**TABLE B WHERE I STORE FOR EVERY DAY WHO IS THERE OR NOT**

| DATE | Name 1 | Name 2 | Name [...] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2024 | YES | YES | ---------- |
| 02/01/2024 | NO | YES | ---------- |

I mean, I don't know if this can be possible using access or not, I've already done with the table A imported from excel but I really can't find a solution to generate as many fields as the records of the first table

Comment: Table B is not a normalized data structure. Should not be a field for each name. If you really want this "spreadsheet", then use VBA to build Table B or manually create fields.

Comment: This design is path to madness. Forget spreadsheet setup and start from scratch to design relational database. Do research and studying to better understand RDBMS concepts. Timekeeping is a common requirement. Can probably buy one for far less than it would cost to build yourself https://www.microsoftaccessexpert.com/Microsoft-Access-Time-Card-Database.aspx. Or maybe free MS template on this page will serve https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/featured-access-templates-e14f25e4-78b6-41de-8278-1afcfc91a9cb - about halfway down.

Comment: Thank you, you're right. I think I will try to create table B with VBA otherwise I'll find something else.

Comment: If you normalized Table B, would not need VBA to build.

Comment: Yep the problem is that I really don't know how to manage this in a different way, so maybe I'll quit this idea and redo in any different way

Answer (score 0):

Your design is not normalized..

Table B - attendance:

| DATE | USER_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 01/01/24 | 1 |
| 01/01/24 | 2 |

This saves a lot of space, avoids redundancy, etc..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Step 1. Transpose table B

| Date | (id) Names | Presence |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.2024 | Name1 | Yes |
| 01.01.2024 | Name2 | Yes |
| 01.01.2024 | ... | ... |
| 01.02.2024 | Name1 | No |
| 01.02.2024 | Name2 | Yes |
| ... | ... | ... |

Step 2. Let's remove redundancy. Let's leave only those who were present

| Date | (id) Names | Presence |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.2024 | Name1 | Yes |
| 01.01.2024 | Name2 | Yes |
| 01.01.2024 | ... | ... |
| 01.02.2024 | Name2 | Yes |
| ... | ... | ... |

Step 3. column "Presence" is no longer needed. We indicate the names of only those who were present

| Date | (id) Names |
| --- | --- |
| 01.01.2024 | Name1 |
| 01.01.2024 | Name2 |
| 01.01.2024 | ... |
| 01.02.2024 | Name2 |
| ... | ... |

Comment: How is this meant to provide an answer according to [answer]? I do not get it. Can you [edit] to make that more obvioud? An explanation of what the solution is and a description of how to implement it would help a lot.